# how to specify generic types for a Dart static extension?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create a static extension on Iterable like so:

```dart
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E, T>(E Function(int index, T item) f) sync* {
    var index = 0;

    for (final item in this) {
      yield f(index, item);
      index = index + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives me an error of:
`The argument type 'T' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.`

Whereas if I cast the compiler is happy:

```dart
extension IterableExtensions on Iterable{
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E, T>(E Function(int index, T item) f) sync* {
    var index = 0;

    for (final item in this) {
      yield f(index, item as T);
      index = index + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually shot yourself in the foot with the first example. The `T` defined in the method signature overrode the `T` in the extension signature. You can see what happened more clearly if you change one of them to something else:

```dart
extension IterableExtensions<U> on Iterable<U> {
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E, T>(E Function(int index, T item) f) sync* {
    var index = 0;

    for (final item in this) {
      yield f(index, item);
      index = index + 1;
    }
  }
}

// Error: The argument type 'U' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.
```

The fix is to remove the `T` from the method signature:

```dart
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<E> mapIndexed<E>(E Function(int index, T item) f) sync* {
    var index = 0;

    for (final item in this) {
      yield f(index, item);
      index = index + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I realise now what happened: I forgot to remove the T from the method signature when I converted it from being just at a normal static function that took a T as its first param to being an extension where that param instead became the implicit "this".